# How to add modules into Apache (mod_dbd and mod_auth_dbd)

Tags: apache, server-side, apache-modules, loadmodule

I have tried my best to see if I can add the modules `mod_dbd` and `mod_auth_dbd` into Apache but I can't seem to get them to work. I am not sure if I am doing this correct, inside the `httpd.conf` file I have this line:

```
LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
```

Is this how you meant to add the module for `mod_dbd` ?

After putting this line of code inside `myhttpd.conf` file, when I try to restart my sever I am getting an error:

> Cannot open shared object file : No such file or directory

Thanks

Comment: Your Apache web server already told you the answer: it cannot find the shared object file, i.e. the mod_dbd.so, from the path you've specified.

Comment: How do I go about doing this ? do I add the mod_dbd.so in the path I specified ??

Comment: I'm not sure which platform you're using. I've checked a CentOS 6 server, mod_dbd comes with the httpd package and its also pre-configured in httpd.conf (exactly the same as in your question) and it loads properly. If you compile the module on your own, you need to put it into your module path.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this manually and get more granular feedback on what is failing.  Inspect the paths.  On my Ubuntu 20 I see there are 33 enabled modules:

```
$ ls /etc/apache2/mods-available/ | wc
    143     143    2096
$ ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled | wc
     33      33     450
```

To enable a module, check if it is already enabled:
`$ ls  /etc/apache2/mods-enabled | grep dbd`

If it is not enabled, Apache2 lets you do this at the command line:
`sudo a2enmod dbd`